# InfluxDb Continuous Query that excludes zeros

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to create a continuous query in InfluxDb to downsample the measurement data to the hourly mean values. I can do that with the continuous query below.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "cq_test_1h" ON "db-name"
BEGIN
    SELECT mean("value") AS "mean_value"
    INTO "downsampled"."downsampled_measurement"
    FROM "autogen"."measurement"
    GROUP BY time(1h)
END
```

But I also want that if the hourly mean equals zero, the result is excluded; so the `downsampled_measurement` series does not contain any zero values. I can make a (nested) query that does what I want, but I don't know how to make this into a continuous query.

```
SELECT mean_value
FROM
    (SELECT mean(value) AS mean_value
    FROM "measurement"
    WHERE time<now()
    GROUP BY time(1h))
WHERE mean_value>0
```

The query above works, but to make it a continuous query it needs an aggregator, `GROUP BY` clause and a duration argument in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT mean(mean_value)
FROM
    (SELECT mean(value) AS mean_value FROM "db-name"."autogen"."measurement"
    WHERE time<now()
    GROUP BY time(1h))
WHERE mean_value>0 AND time<now()
GROUP BY time(1h)
```

However, this query no longer returns any values. How can I make a continuous query that excludes zeros?